# Finding sample by simple random sampling

Tags: self-study, sampling, sample-size

I know population (Population size = N). But, I want to find a sample for this population by using simple random sampling. How to find this sample.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: What software are you using? Excel, R, other?

Comment: Could you go into more details?

Comment: spss or excel @l'ombradel'atzavara

Comment: For example, how to accept tolerance quatity (d) for population sample size N=30? According to you, what do you accept d? @l'ombradel'atzavara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this. I'll offer an Excel solution, since that was mentioned in the comments. I'll also offer an R solution, which I prefer.

Excel solution:
If you have a list of IDs as a column in Excel, generate a column of uniform random numbers in (0,1) using =RAND(). The command doesn't need any arguments. Because Excel can cause trouble by regenerating that column and creating a new set of numbers, copy that column and paste just the values over top of it using paste -> special -> values. That gets rid of the formula and keeps the numbers. Now sort by the column of random numbers and keep the number of rows you wanted starting from the top.

R solution:
Read in the IDs and simply use the sample function. For example,

```
# simple random sample of 70 from 7777
N <- 7777
IDs <- 1:N
srs <- sample(IDs, 70, replace=F)
sort(srs)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. Well, for population size N =30 , how to accept tolerance quantity (d)? What do you accept tolerance quatity for N=30?